# Including pre-trained Keras models in a package

Tags: r, keras

I have developed a Shiny package that uses pre-trained keras models (in .h5 format). These are stored in a folder called models. I want to package this app and distribute it to a client. This is the local folder on my Mac: 
[image]
After building the package (R studio, build tool), the compiled library is like this (as located under resources/library/mypackage/)
[image]
The model folder is not present anymore. Skimming Hadley's book (http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/), it seems like only .RDS files can be included in a package. Is that correct? Is there a way to include .h5 files in an R package?