# How to include keras model in R package?

Tags: r, keras, package, hdf5

I am building an R package and I would like to include a pretrained keras model (in hdf5 format) in it. I am wondering, how to do so correctly.

I found many examples of data included within the packages, but all of them were in formats acceptable by the data() function.

I also found a similar question here:
[Including pre-trained Keras models in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333837/including-pre-trained-keras-models-in-a-package)

But this remains unanswered, and I have the same doubts as the author of this thread. So how to do this properly and in a CRAN-accepted manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place files with any format in the 'inst' folder, and then access them at runtime from R code with `system.file()`

For example, place the h5 file in `"package_name/inst/pretrained-models/model.h5"`, and then access it from R code with `system.file("pretrained-models/model.h5", package = "package_name")`